# How to update specific filed in mongodb document using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to search `product` document by ObjectId and update specific field `listed` using Spring data framework. 
I get error from IDE when I try to use `update` method on injected `MongoOperations`

```
@Repository
public class ProductDao  {
@Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

public void cancel(Long id) {
        mongoOperations.update("{"_id":"00000000001"}","$set{"listed":"False"}"); // error // something like that
    }
}
```

I think I need to use `DBCollection` but I have issues setting it up. To update field I need to use **$set**

How to make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the ability to test this at the moment but this is the way you should go about it. I am assuming that your product documents are mapped in a Product.class in the snippet below

```
mongoOperations.updateFirst(new Query(where("_id").is("00000000001")),Update.update("listed", "False"), Product.class)
```

If you wanted to update many documents that match the query you should use the `updateMulti` function instead.

Also, the two imports you need are :

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
```